# Tensorflow: Error rate doesn't improve even with more iterations or changing learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm using tensorflow to deploy my own simple CNN with mnist dataset.
I've finally deployed my convnet and the code can run without any error or warning. However, the error rate in the terminal is always 0.098 and doesn't improve even if I change the number of iterations, or the learning rate. Where did i go wrong? Can anyone help me?

My code (MyConvNet.py):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from MyNet import weight_variable,bias_variable,conv_layer,pooling_layer,relu_layer,fully_connecd,softmax_layer


def compute_accuracy(v_xs,v_ys):
    global prediction
    y_pre = sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={xs:v_xs})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pre,1),tf.argmax(v_ys,1))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
    result = sess.run(acc,feed_dict={xs:v_xs,ys:v_ys})
    return result


xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
x_img = tf.reshape(xs,[-1,28,28,1])

########## LAYER DEFINITION START ##########
# layer 1
conv1_w = weight_variable([5,5,1,6]) # [cols,rows,channels,n]
conv1_b = bias_variable([6])
# [28*28*1]->[24*24*6]
conv1 = conv_layer(x_img, conv1_w, name='conv1') + conv1_b
# [24*24*6]->[12*12*6]
pool1 = pooling_layer(conv1, name='pool1')
relu1 = relu_layer(pool1,name='relu1')

# layer 2
conv2_w = weight_variable([5,5,6,16]) # [cols,rows,channels,n]
conv2_b = bias_variable([16])
# [12*12*6]->[8*8*16]
conv2 = conv_layer(relu1, conv2_w, name='conv2') + conv2_b
# [8*8*16]->[4*4*16]
pool2 = pooling_layer(conv2, name='pool2')
relu2 = relu_layer(pool2, name='relu2')

# layer 3 (fc)
fc_in_size = (relu2.get_shape()[1]*relu2.get_shape()[2]*relu2.get_shape()[3]).value
fc3_w = weight_variable([fc_in_size,120])
fc3_b = bias_variable([120])
relu2_col = tf.reshape(relu2,[-1,fc_in_size])
fc3 = fully_connecd(relu2_col,fc3_w, name='fc3')+fc3_b
relu3 = relu_layer(fc3, name='relu3')

# layer 4 (fc)
fc4_w = weight_variable([120,10])
fc4_b = bias_variable([10])
fc4 = fully_connecd(relu3,fc4_w, name='fc3')+fc4_b
relu4 = relu_layer(fc4, name='relu4')

# layer 5 (prediction)
prediction = softmax_layer(relu4)

# training solver
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys*tf.log(prediction),
                                              reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
########## LAYER DEFINITION END ##########



# start training
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for step in range(500):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={xs:batch_xs, ys:batch_ys})
    if step % 50 == 0:
        print( compute_accuracy(mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels) )

sess.close()
```

and here is MyNet.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape,stddev=0.1):
    init = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def bias_variable(shape):
    init = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def conv_layer(bottom,Weights,name='conv_layer'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        # stride=[1,x_dir,y_dir,1]
        return tf.nn.conv2d(bottom,Weights,strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID')

def pooling_layer(bottom,name='pooling_layer'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(bottom,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID')

def relu_layer(bottom,name='relu_layer'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):    
        return tf.nn.relu(bottom)

def fully_connecd(bottom,Weights,name='fc'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        return tf.matmul(bottom,Weights)

def softmax_layer(bottom,name='softmax'):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        return tf.nn.softmax(bottom)
```

here is the output from the terminal

```
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
0.098
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your weight initialization replace tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev) with:

```
def weight_variable(shape,stddev=0.1):
    init = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev = stddev)
    return tf.Variable(init)
```

See my explanation in the comment. To illustrate:

```
test=tf.truncated_normal([1000000], 0.1)
plt.hist(test.eval(session=sess),50)
test2=tf.truncated_normal([1000000], stddev=.1)
plt.hist(test2.eval(session=sess),50)
```

[image]

Comment: Explanation: With your code you set a truncated normal distribution with a mean of 0.1(which is the 2nd argument of truncated_normal) , and a stddev of 1.0 (which is the default value). This results in problematic large weights.

Comment: Thank Wojtek for helping me a lot.!!
I took your suggestion to set 
    tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev)    
to
    tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev = stddev)    
thank you for remind me that the second argument is the mean of the distribution(I don't even know that :P).
But after I have this modification the error changes from 0.098 to 0.0607 and still always keep displaying 0.0607 which didn't have any improvement no matter what iteration, learning rate or optimizer i set.

Comment: Set the learning rate of the GradientDescentOptimizer to 0.1, set the steps in your loop to 10000 and print out every 500 steps. That is the settings I used to try out your code and it ends up with an increasing acc. Did you change the code since the post ?

Comment: Wooooooowwwwww!!!! It works!! 
Actually I only change the iteration and solver :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, but you train a 5-layers neural network using a simple gradient descent optimizer with only 500 iterations. It's not enough. I suggest you :

- Print the cross entropy during training (if it doesn't decrease : you
  probably have an error in your code )
- Increase your number of iterations (10,000 for example)
- Change your optimizer to speed-up learning (Momentum or Adam like
  [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html))

Comment: Thank you first trying to help me!!
Actually, I tried to set the training iteration from 500 through 10000 but the error was always 0.098. 
And I also used  tf.train.AdamOptimizer (learning rate set from 0.0001~0.1) to learn my simple net but the error still be 0.098.
So I guess there must be something wrong in my code but I can't figure it out where it is